# Lie algebra homomorphisms on sum

Tags: linear-transformations, lie-algebras

So here is a question: if $p$ is a homomorphism from a lie algebra $K$ to lie algebra $Q$, I know that $p$ preserves the bracket in $K$, but does $p$ also preserve addition operation? Since $K$ is a lie algebra, it is also a vector space, so I can define $k_1+k_2$ of elements in $K$, but does $p(k_1+k_2)$ equal to $p(k_1)+p(k_2)$?

In other words, are they linear?

Comment: Please use Mathjax syntax (see help center)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is part of the definition of Lie algebra homomorphism: it is a *linear* map $f$ from $\mathfrak g$ into $\mathfrak h$ such that, if $X,Y\in\mathfrak g$, $f\bigl([X,Y]\bigr)=\bigl[f(X),f(Y)\bigr]$.